# Magento - Dynamic Listbox in a custom module

Tags: magento

I wish to make a dynamic listbox in a magento custom module, in magento backend, with a custom table in database, and than process this data to execute an update query in another table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to define the source model of this select box and then make a class for it and query or add what you need to this select. For example open up the "yesno" class and see how it adds the values:

```
<frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
<source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
```

Comment: where have I to put this lines of code ?? in config.xml , yes ??

Comment: its ment for system.xml where you define your adminhtml elements . as i understand you need to add a select to administration page

Comment: How can I then call this class in my module backend interface ??

Comment: <source_model> is the class the select calls for it source